# Type hint in Python tuples

Tags: python, python-typing

I have the code below, I understand that the function takes 2 integers, so `(n : int, m : int)`, and it returns a tuple with integers of any length, therefore `-> tuple[int,...]`:

I think this also correct for an empty tuple `T : tuple[()]` since the tuple at some point in the function has only one value.

However I get this error

```
main.py:14: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Tuple[int]", variable has type "Tuple[]")
```

What am I missing?

```
def vectorise(n : int, m : int) -> tuple[int,...]:
  '''creates a tuple of element n repeated m times'''
  T : tuple[()] = () #empty tuple
  counter : int = 0
  while counter < m:
    T = T + (n,) #in Python (n,) is a tuple with one element n
    counter+=1
  #as a result, T can be of arbitrary length
  return T

L = vectorise(100, 5)
```

Comment: Why not start as you mean to go on - `T: tuple[int, ...] = ...`.

Comment: "What am I missing?": The type for `T` needs to at least be equivalent (able to encompass) the intended `return` type. As you have hinted `T` to be an EMPTY tuple, you cannot then return a different type - hence the type incompatibility error. You could instead add the OTHER hint for the return type e.g. `tuple[int,...] | tuple[()]` to cater for both eventualities.

Answer (score 2):

The variable `T` has the type "empty tuple". You are trying to assign something to it which is not an empty tuple. Therefore, you get a type error.

You either need to make sure that you are only assigning empty tuples to `T`, or make sure that the type of `T` admits non-empty tuples.